# Convert UserControl to ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resourcedictionary

I'd like to try out this globalization thing in WPF:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515960/Globalization-in-WPF-using-ResourceDictionary

Unforunately the second step got me already it says: convert UserControl to ResourceDictionary

How can I make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you create a simple `UserControl` and name it however you like.
Then you open the .xaml file and change `<UserControl` to `<ResourceDictionary`.

Then you have to open de .xaml.cs file of the UserControl and add the two attributes (the ones between brackets []) to the class:

```
[ExportMetadata("Culture", "en-US")]
[Export(typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
public partial class EnglishLanguage : ResourceDictionary
{
    public EnglishLanguage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And add this using reference to the list of usings:
`using System.ComponentModel.Composition;`

The compiler will notify you that `ExportMetadata`, `Export` and the using reference  could not be resolved. That's because you need to add the reference to the composition DLL to your project manually.

In the solution explorer under you project, right click `References` and click `Add reference`. A list of available DLL files will pop up under `Assembly` - `Framework`.
Check the box for `System.ComponentModel.Composition`, click OK and build your project.

Now you're all set ;)